# AFNetworking + AFHTTPRequestOperation not being able to save Array

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, xcode, afnetworking-2

So I am trying to access a json file online and I can get the contents of the JSON file when I run the completion block using AFHTTPRequestOperation method. But when I try to NSLog outside the completion block, it becomes null. I was wondering why this is happening and how I would go about fixing this. Below is the code I have so far:

```
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    [operation setCredential:credentials];
    [operation setResponseSerializer:[AFJSONResponseSerializer alloc]];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Success %@", responseObject);
        jsonOutputData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:responseObject];
        self.newsFeedArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[jsonOutputData copy]];


    }failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){
        NSLog(@"Failure: %@", error);
    }];

    [manager.operationQueue addOperation:operation];
    NSLog(@"%@", self.newsFeedArray);
```

The NSLog with Success shows the JSON but the NSLog with the self.newsFeedArray shows (null). I am just wondering why this is happening. If you need more clarification, let me know. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The success and failure blocks get called asynchronously. So `self.newsFeedArray` simply has not been set yet at the time of the last `NSLog` call, because the operation has not completed.

You could wait for the operation to complete (e.g., `[operation waitUntilFinished]`) but you almost certainly don't want to do this, especially on the main thread. Rather have the completion blocks trigger the desired behaviour.

Comment: Would putting the AFHTTP portion in viewWillAppear be fine and keep the last 'NSLog' in viewDidLoad?

Comment: @hparmar The view is independent of the network operation. Even if you find places to put the code where it works most of the time for you, it may fail if the network is slow, etc. You could show a loading indicator meanwhile and only populate the view with the data once it becomes available (call a method to do so from the success block). Also remember that the operation may fail (the failure block is called) for various reasons that are out of your control.